# Unable to make border around form

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a border for my form. Just like we can find around example input group [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)
My code is:

```
<div style="border-color:red;border-radius:3px;background-color:#999">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm trying with setting:

- border-color
- border-radius
  with no effects. 
  Can anyone suggest me how to do it?

[Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/COo1oSASTi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add it directly to your form via the css file?

```
form[role=search] { border: 3px solid red; padding: 1em; }
```

[Example based on yours](http://www.bootply.com/ndTKKzjx7r)

Answer (score 1):

You must set "border-width". "border-radius" is for rounded corners, not the thickness of the border. "border-style" defaults to "solid", and is therefore optional. You could also use the shorthand "border: 2px solid red;".

Comment: You mean `border: 2px solid red;`, not `background: 2px solid red;`

Answer (score 1):

Update two things in your existing code

1. Update the div's css `border: 1px solid red;`
2. Add a `clearfix` class to your parent div since you have used `navbar-left` class to the form